# GitLab reconfigure Failed

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab

Estoy tratando de instalar GitLab en ubuntu server 16.04 en Hyper V y me arroja este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado cambiar el external url, pero me sigue arrojando error. Es para uso interno, no es necesario que se pueda acceder desde afuera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si le sirve a alguien en el futuro.

Yo tenía todo bien configurado y me daba error instalación tras instalación, lo conseguí solucionar actualizando todos los paquetes de mi Ubuntu Server, incluso los que retiene el sistema, que son los que estaban dándome error.